# How to send a texture to a shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I'm having issue sending a texture to a shader. Here is the code i'm using.

```
uniforms = {
    "rightTexture":  { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/doors_right_512.png" ) },
    "tDiffuse":  { type: "t", value: null },
    "aspect":    { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2( 512, 512 ) },
};
uniform sampler2D rightTexture;
vec3 sample;
sample = texture2D(rightTexture, vUv).rgb;
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(sample), 1.0);
```

When I'm sampling tDiffuse everything looks fine but if I use rightTexture I just get a black screen. Why is this?

Comment: are you waiting for the texture to load?

Comment: Check it uploads correctly with [WebGL Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webgl-inspector/ogkcjmbhnfmlnielkjhedpcjomeaghda?hl=en)

Comment: I'm defiantly having an issue with loading. Sorry I wasn't sure if there was a fundamental difference between tDiffuse and a normal texture. I'm not quite sure of the correct way to make things wait until loading is done. I guess I have to use some kind of call back function? Any suggested reading?

Comment: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=507 it's not three.js, but you could probably use the same idea.